# How to calculate the circumference of a graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The **circumference** of a graph is the length of any longest cycle in the graph. I couldn't find a specific command to calculate the circumference of a graph or find a longest cycles. Using `FindCycle` is a viable option, but I believe it is not the best solution.

```
Circumference[g_] := Module[{n, k, cycle}, n = VertexCount[g];
  k = n;
  While[k >= 2, cycle = FindCycle[g, {k}];
   If[cycle =!= {}, Return[k]];
   k--;];
  0  (*If no cycle is found,circumference is 0*)]
g = GraphData["TutteGraph"];
Circumference[g];
(*out: 45*)
```

Although determining the circumference of a graph is **NP-hard** (as it may be equal to the number of vertices), there might be some methods available for relatively small-scale graphs.

---

I have searched Stack Overflow, and most people suggest using a **backtracking** method because there is no efficient algorithm for general graphs. However, I haven't found the specific implementation details from there.

- [The longest cycle in an undirected graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35650783/the-longest-cycle-in-an-undirected-graph)
- [Is there any efficient algorithm to find the length of the longest cycle in a undirected graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55625479/is-there-any-efficient-algorithm-to-find-the-length-of-the-longest-cycle-in-a-un)
- [Longest cycle in a digraph](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/51017/longest-cycle-in-a-digraph)

I found the following C language version on [GitHub](https://github.com/coldwarrior5/Graph-analyser/tree/master/longest-cycle). I tested it with Tutte's graph, and it took about 5 minutes to run. (To prevent the code from becoming invalid in the future, I have copied it below):

```
/*
Dean Babić
0036470256
*/
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> // needed for reading input file

#include <limits.h> // needed to check bounding conditions
#include <errno.h>  // needed for error codes
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
/* We are on Windows */
# define strtok_r strtok_s
# include <io.h> // needed to check file availability
#endif
#if defined(_UNIX)
#include <unistd.h> // needed to check file availability
#endif
void PrepareNeighborHoodMatrix(int argc, char* argv[]);
char* ReadFile(char *argv);
void ReadNeighborhoodMatrix(char *readFile);
void PrintMatrix();
void PrintCycle(int* cycle, int length);
int FindLongestCycle(int** cycle);
int BFS(int currentVertice, int beginVertice, int length, int maxLength, int *visited, int** list);
void ErrorHandler(int errorCode);
void Destructor();

int noOfVertices;
int **neighborhood;

const int base = 10;

// Main method, it calls other methods
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int length;
    // Read the neighborhood matrix
    PrepareNeighborHoodMatrix(argc, argv);
    int* cycle = (int*)malloc((noOfVertices + 1) * sizeof(int));
    // Find the longest cycle
    length = FindLongestCycle(&cycle);
    printf("%d\n", length);
    // Clear the heap allocated memory
    PrintCycle(cycle, length + 1);
    Destructor();
    return 0;
}

// Ensures that everything is correct before the longest cycle can be found
void PrepareNeighborHoodMatrix(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char *readFile;
    // Check if the user has given input parameters
    if (argc < 2)
        ErrorHandler(-1);
    // Check if the file is accessible or read protected
    #if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
        if (_access(argv[1], 0))
            ErrorHandler(-2);
    #endif
    #if defined(_UNIX)
        if (access(argv[1], F_OK | R_OK))
            ErrorHandler(-2);
    #endif
    // Check if there are any errors whilst reading the file
    readFile = ReadFile(argv[1]);
    if (readFile == NULL)
        ErrorHandler(-3);
    // Now fill the neghborhood matrix
    ReadNeighborhoodMatrix(readFile);
}

// Reads file and stores it into a char array
char*  ReadFile(char *filename)
{
    char *buffer = NULL;
    int string_size, read_size;
    FILE *handler = fopen(filename, "rb");

    if (handler)
    {
        fseek(handler, 0, SEEK_END);
        string_size = ftell(handler);
        rewind(handler);

        buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (string_size + 1));
        read_size = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), string_size, handler);
        buffer[string_size] = '\0';

        if (string_size != read_size)
        {
            free(buffer);
            buffer = NULL;
        }
        fclose(handler);
    }
    return buffer;
}

// Fills neighborhood matrix with values contained in char array
void ReadNeighborhoodMatrix(char *readFile)
{
    char *token;
    char *str = readFile;
    token = strtok_r(str, "\n\r", &str);
    char *endptr;
    long result = strtol(token, &endptr, base);
    if (endptr == token || ((result >= INT_MAX || result <= INT_MIN) && errno == ERANGE))
    {
        free(readFile);
        ErrorHandler(-4);
    }

    noOfVertices = (int)result;
    neighborhood = (int**)malloc(noOfVertices * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfVertices; i++)
        neighborhood[i] = (int*)malloc(noOfVertices * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < noOfVertices; i++)
    {
        token = strtok_r(str, "\n\r", &str);
        if (token == NULL || strlen(token) == 0)
        {
            free(readFile);
            ErrorHandler(-6);
        }

        char *strcopy = (char*)calloc(strlen(token) + 1, sizeof(char));
        strcpy(strcopy, token);
        char *elem = strcopy;
        for (int j = 0; j < noOfVertices; j++)
        {
            token = strtok_r(elem, " ", &elem);
            if (token == NULL || strlen(token) == 0)
            {
                free(readFile);
                free(strcopy);
                ErrorHandler(-6);
            }

            result = strtol(token, &endptr, base);
            if (endptr == token || ((result >= INT_MAX || result <= INT_MIN) && errno == ERANGE))
            {
                free(readFile);
                free(strcopy);
                ErrorHandler(-5);
            }

            neighborhood[i][j] = (int)result;
        }
        free(strcopy);
    }
}

// Test to see if the matrix loaded correctly
void PrintMatrix()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfVertices; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < noOfVertices; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", neighborhood[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void PrintCycle(int* cycle, int length)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", cycle[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

/*
Looks inside of neighborhood matrix to find cycles
Returns maximum cycle length
*/
int FindLongestCycle(int** cycle)
{
    int length = 0;
    int *visited = (int*)calloc(noOfVertices, sizeof(int));
    int *tempCycle = (int*)malloc((noOfVertices + 1) * sizeof(int));
    
    // Iterate over all nodes and set them as start nodes, some nodes may be leaf nodes
    // or they may be inside of a smaller cycle
    for (int currentVertice = 0; currentVertice < noOfVertices; currentVertice++)
    {
        // Call recursive Breadth First Search method to try and find longest cycle.
        // If it is longer than current maximum, update maximum length
        tempCycle[0] = currentVertice;
        int currentLength = BFS(currentVertice, currentVertice, 0, length, visited, &tempCycle);
        if (currentLength > length)
        {
            length = currentLength;
            for(int i = 0; i < length + 1; i++)
            {
                (*cycle)[i] = tempCycle[i];
            }
        }
    }

    free(visited);
    return length;
}

/*
Recursive method for traversing the tree
In this case graph in some way we can perceive tree as unraveled graph where leaf nodes
represent either a root node or some node that closes a cycle or simply leaf node of a graph
Returns new maximum length
*/
int BFS(int currentVertice, int beginVertice, int length, int maxLength, int *visited, int** list)
{
    int newLength = maxLength;
    visited[currentVertice] = 1;

    for (int nextVertice = 0; nextVertice < noOfVertices; nextVertice++)
    {
        if (neighborhood[currentVertice][nextVertice] == 1)
        {
            // If next node is root node then update maximum length if new length is greater
            if (nextVertice == beginVertice && length > 1 && length + 1 > maxLength)
            {
                newLength = length + 1;
                (*list)[length] = nextVertice;
            }
            // If next node hasn't yet been visited recursivelly go into that node
            else if (!visited[nextVertice])
            {
                (*list)[length + 1] = nextVertice;
                newLength = BFS(nextVertice, beginVertice, length + 1, newLength, visited, list);
            }
        }
    }
    // After there are no more legitimate moves, return new maximum length and remove
    // your node from visited nodes
    visited[currentVertice] = 0;
    return newLength;
}

// Describes the type of error to the user and handles the termination of program
void ErrorHandler(int errorCode)
{
    char *errorText;
    switch (errorCode)
    {
    case -1:
        errorText = "Not enough input parametres";
        break;
    case -2:
        errorText = "The file does not exit or is not readable";
        break;
    case -3:
        errorText = "Error whilst reading the file";
        break;
    case -4:
        errorText = "Wrong vertice number, check input file";
        break;
    case -5:
        errorText = "Wrong weight number inside of the neighborhood matrix, check input file";
        break;
    case -6:
        errorText = "Wrong width or height of the neighborhood matrix, check input file";
        break;
    default:
        errorText = "Unknown error occured";
        break;
    }
    printf("%s\n", errorText);
    Destructor();
    exit(errorCode);
}

// Handles memory deallocation when the program is exiting
void Destructor()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfVertices; i++) {
        free(neighborhood[i]);
    }
    free(neighborhood);
}
```

My operating system is Windows, and I execute the program as follows:

```
 Measure-Command  {./main.exe Tuttegraph.txt >longestcycle.txt}
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 5
Seconds           : 32
Milliseconds      : 327
Ticks             : 3323274512
TotalDays         : 0.00384638253703704
TotalHours        : 0.0923131808888889
TotalMinutes      : 5.53879085333333
TotalSeconds      : 332.3274512
TotalMilliseconds : 332327.4512
```

Tuttegraph.txt:

```
46

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
```

longestcycle.txt:

```
45
0 12 31 35 37 44 45 43 42 32 33 4 5 6 29 30 23 22 20 21 13 15 16 17 18 14 10 38 25 26 34 28 27 3 2 11 34 28 27 3 2 11 11 8 11 0
```

Comment: You seem to be looking for an algorithm rather than an implementation. That question may be better asked on a different forum (e.g. Math SE). Once you have a method in mind, then we can help you implement it in Mathematica. Alternatively, you may be interested in [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/igraphm-a-mathematica-interface-for-igraph.html), an interface that allows you to use igraph functionality from within Mathematica.

Comment: You maybe have already seen this, but there are formulas for the graph circumference of some specific classes of graphs (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphCircumference.html). This isn't really helpful for a general algorithm though

Comment: `CircumferenceB[g_] := Module[{k = VertexCount[g]},  While[k >= 2 && FindCycle[g, {--k}] === {} ]; k /. 1 -> 0]` seems faster than `Circumference`

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you! I'm not sure `igraph` has a corresponding command.

Comment: In Stack Overflow, most suggestions recommend using the backtracking method to find the longest cycle.  For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35650783/the-longest-cycle-in-an-undirected-graph. However, the specific implementation details might not be clear. Although we found a program on GitHub, it appears that the computation is not particularly fast. See https://github.com/coldwarrior5/Graph-analyser/tree/master/longest-cycle/src.